# Python live mouse smoothing

Tags: python, mouse

I want to know if it's possible to make a live mouse smoothing movement? Like, you move your mouse with the default mouse input, the real mouse, but the movement on the screen in smooth. 
I found this to move the mouse, but not direcly.

```
from __future__ import division
import autopy
import time

x0, y0 = 800, 300
xf, yf = 100, 600

total_time = 5.00  # in seconds
draw_steps = 1000  # total times to update cursor

dx = (xf-x0)/draw_steps
dy = (yf-y0)/draw_steps
dt = total_time/draw_steps

for n in xrange(draw_steps):
    x = int(x0+dx*n)
    y = int(y0+dy*n)
    autopy.mouse.move(x,y)
    time.sleep(dt)
```

Could someone lead me to the right direction ?

Comment: I also found this : 
`import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(10,10)`